# How do I cast a geometry type for mixed geometries (polygons & multipolygons) in 4326? `::geometry(4326) as shape` doesn't work

Tags: database, postgresql, gis, postgis, geography

I'd like to update the geometry definition to include a specific SRID

```
CREATE MATERIALIZED VIEW published.ql_cmd_cruise_layer_web
TABLESPACE pg_default
AS SELECT ql_cmd_cruise_layer_web.cruise_id,
    ql_cmd_cruise_layer_web.cruise,
    ql_cmd_cruise_layer_web.shape_wgs84::geometry(4326) AS shape_wgs84,
    ql_cmd_cruise_layer_web.cruise_data_url
   FROM oracle_fdw.ql_cmd_cruise_layer_web
WITH DATA;
```

The geom column holds both polygons and multipolygons, so I can't do `::geometry(Poygon,4326)` which has worked on other, simpler tables.

Using `::geometry(4326)` results in `SQL Error [22023]: ERROR: Invalid geometry type modifier: 4326 Position: 1094`

Comment: What type is `ql_cmd_cruise_layer_web.shape_wgs84`?

Comment: The usual procedure is to fix the column type to multipolygon and use `st_multi` to promote any `polygons`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You must give a geometry type. Since you have mixed content, you can use the generic `geometry` type during the cast.

```
ql_cmd_cruise_layer_web.shape_wgs84::geometry(geometry,4326) AS shape_wgs84,
```

Comment: Brilliant! I didn't know you could use the generic geometry type during the cast. That's worked perfectly

Answer (score 1):

If `ql_cmd_cruise_layer_web.shape_wgs84` is already geometry (but without a declared spatial reference), then use `ST_SetSRID(ql_cmd_cruise_layer_web.shape_wgs84, 4326)`. (I wasn't even aware that what you're currently doing is an option, so `ST_SetSRID` seems normative.)

Comment: It won't serve the OP objective. Setting the SRID will affect the individual records, not the column definition.

Comment: Yeah that's fair